# Sites for learning the business side?

Tags: production

(Sorry if this is off-topic. I couldn't find any place more appropriate for the subject).

Most of the questions that are asked in this board, and most of the courses that you find when you search online for subjects like "video production", are related to the technical and creative side: how to learn Final Cut/Premiere, how to light a greenscreen, how to use a 3D program, how to format and write a screenplay...

However, I have found very few courses about the business side. Things like: how do film/TV rights get sold around the world, what's the decision-making process when putting together a TV schedule, how to decide which shows to develop...

To put in other words: most of the courses and questions I find are about learning how to be a good camera operator, editor, director... Where are to courses to learn how to be a... say, TV or production company executive?

I suspect that I'd have to join a MBA specialized in media, or something like that. Am I right? Are there any online courses (Coursera, EdX, etc.) that cover this subject?

Answer (score 2):

Most undergraduate media programs have a "The Business of..." course in their curricula. It used to be "The Business of Television" or "The Business of Film". Nowadays, it is probably listed as "The Business of Media" or "The Business of Digital Media."

Unfortunately, those classes seem to be offered only intermittently. As an undergraduate I found the business class I managed to take essential for understanding the industry I was trying to break into. Now, as a seasoned professional, I cannot understand why those courses aren't required to graduate. But those aren't the fun or sexy classes, unlike the production classes.

The most relevant MOOC I could find was on the [music industry](https://www.coursera.org/learn/musicbiz). I suspect most media programs haven't adopted online delivery because of the difficulty in producing media without the group work you get with an in-person class.